# Altium: Comment field of schematic symbols

Tags: altium

Eagle does not contain a Value field for the schematic symbols. Rather, it contains a comment field. From what I know this field shall contain the resistance, capacitance and inductance value for resistor, capacitor and inductor component respectively. In these cases, the comment field must always be visible.

Now what is not clear is what to do with other components. These are diodes, transistor, connector  and ICs. What is the comment field supposed to contain for these components? I mean, one can put anything, but what is the correct information to put into it? Someone will say put the part number. But if this is true then why don't we put part number of the resistors, capacitors and inductors and have a third field that shall contain their value since all components do not have a value field you see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no requirement for what goes there other than what others might ask you to do. (e.g. an organization requires specific formatting to ensure schematics produced by different engineers follow the same format, or a tool that parses schematics--such as a simulator plugin--may require specific fields to contain specific data.) Unless someone or something else requires something specific to be there, the field is just there for your reference, and you can put whatever you personally find most useful in it.

Below, I've written a bit about my personal practices. This should not be considered any sort of recognised standard; it's just what I do and what I've found useful.

---

What I do with the equivalent field in KiCad (called "Value") is put the value of resistors, capacitors, inductors, and the odd other component where a value makes sense (e.g. zener diodes' breakdown voltages, or battery pack voltages), and put the "reduced" part number (by which I mean, for instance, Si2318 instead of Si2318DS-T1-E3) for ICs, transistors, diodes, and connectors where a specific part number has been chosen and/or is important. For parts where any generic part meeting given specifications can be used and I want to leave that open, I'll put the requirements--e.g. "BNC", or "2 A Schottky", or what-have-you.

Passive parts with specific requirements may get additional annotations, such as "1 μF 50 V" to specify that the capacitor needs to be 50 V rated, or "51.1 kΩ ±0.1%" if a resistor needs to be more precise than standard (usually only where the requirement isn't obvious).

I then typically add additional "manufacturer" and "part number" fields where I put the manufacturer's name and the entire part number for each part that needs one. Sometimes passive components remain generic where any old 0402 package 1 kΩ resistor (for instance) will do. (I usually also put an additional "minimum voltage rating" field on capacitors for quick reference when choosing parts, so I can have that information in the BOM.)

Comment: The comment field is also a good place to force grouping of heterogeneous & homogeneous (multi-section components) when performing auto-annotation.

Comment: @qrk I have no experience with Eagle, so I wasn't aware it could be used like this. It can't in KiCad (the auto-annotation system in KiCad is somewhat limited, though it does keep multi-unit parts together with UUIDs set when you place them).

Comment: My comment was directed towards Altium. Altium can group multi-section parts based on a number of different fields, the comment field being the one I use.